# What does lsof|gawk '$4~/txt/{next};/REG.*\(deleted\)$/{printf ">/proc/%s/fd/%d\n", $2,$4}' command mean

Tags: command-line

I'm reading some articles and I've seen this command:

```
lsof|gawk '$4~/txt/{next};/REG.*\(deleted\)$/{printf ">/proc/%s/fd/%d\n", $2,$4}'
```

Could some body help me to understand it

Comment: +1 & favorite because it's an interesting question. :-)

Answer (score 7):

This command will **print files from `lsof` that need truncation.**

(It actually **does not remove or truncate** any files).

`lsof` will return a list of open files (file descriptors) that is piped into the awk which processes it as follows.

`gawk '$4~/txt/{next};/REG.*\(deleted\)$/{printf ">/proc/%s/fd/%d\n", $2,$4}'`

The above expression contains two regular expressions separated by a semi colon `;`

lets consider the first part `gawk '$4~/txt/{next};`

Here, if the 4th field contains `txt` then  the next line of text will be read, which the script will start processing from the start again.

The `next` statement forces awk to immediately stop processing the current record and go on to the next record. This means that no further rules are executed for the current record, and the rest of the current rule's action isn't executed.

Now lets consider the second part of the script  `/REG.*\(deleted\)$/{printf ">/proc/%s/fd/%d\n", $2,$4}'`

Here if the line matches the regular expression `/REG.*\(deleted\)$` (the `$` means that `(deleted)` should be the last word on the line), it just prints `>/proc/%s/fd/%d\n", $2,$4`.

In lsof command `$4` is the file descriptor number (for example `53w`, the `w` means the filer has been opened for writing) or filetype, depending on the file. The `%d` in the `printf` ensures that only the numbers will be printed, removing any text characters (like the `w`). `$2` prints the process id of process which uses the file so it will print something like `>/proc/3989/fd/53` and so on it will print all files that have been deleted but whose file descriptor remains open, in other words, file descriptors that can be truncated safely.

Answer (score 2):

This command will truncate deleted files from lsof.

This first will list open files`lsof`

then search for lines recursively one then one`{next}` that contain REG `'$4~/txt/{next};/REG.*\(deleted\)$/` as the fourth parameter then this process relative to this line will be deleted

and then print all results without the lines containing REG and marked as deleted.`{printf ">/proc/%s/fd/%d\n", $2,$4}'`

Comment: I think you should explain the different parts of the command (at least to get my upvote).

Comment: check my update

Comment: When did an awk statement with regex and a print staement started truncating actual contents.You need to pass this command to a `sh` for actual truncation and morever there are two regular expressions there not one as in your explanation